# create individual arrays from np.zeros array using ones for each separate row and column of original matrix

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, for-loop, numpy-slicing

I have a screen composed of 6 rows x 6 columns of alphanumeric characters (e.g p300 speller) I would like to create an array for each of the possible rows and columns  as they illuminate (12 total). when specific column/row is illuminated, fill it with ones, while the rest of the matrix is filled with zeros. Eventually, I would like associate specific matrix with a time-event when it happened on the screen.

Slicing rows/columns individually, generate variables for each of the 12 outputs needed.

```
event_mtx = np.zeros((6,6), dtype=np.int)
_event_mtx = np.zeros((6,6), dtype=np.int)
#replace first row with ones
event_mtx[0]=1
# or replace last column with ones
_event_mtx[:,5]=1
```

new to python and coding, loop should help make this easier. Below is what I attempted for just the rows. Generates ones for each row, however leaves the previous row still filled with ones and continues to build with each iteration, filling up 6x6 array with ones. Creating a "new_event" array to pass the current iteration doesn't seem to help either.  How can I generate individual array in the loop without building on the previous one?  Thoughts/comments appreciated

```
event_mtx = np.zeros((6,6), dtype=np.int)
#new_event =np.zeros((6,6), dtype=np.int)

for i in range(len(event_mtx)):
    for j in range(len(event_mtx[j])):
        event_mtx[0+i] = 1
        #np.new_event = event_mtx

    print(event_mtx)
    #print(new_event)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few possibilities:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> 
>>> rows = np.zeros((6, 6, 6), dtype=int)
>>> np.einsum('iij->ij', rows)[...] = 1
>>> cols = np.zeros((6, 6, 6), dtype=int)
>>> np.einsum('iji->ij', cols)[...] = 1
>>> 
>>> for block in (rows, cols):
...     for m in zip(*block):
...         print(list(map(''.join, map(map, 6*(str,), m))))
...     print()
... 
['111111', '000000', '000000', '000000', '000000', '000000']
['000000', '111111', '000000', '000000', '000000', '000000']
['000000', '000000', '111111', '000000', '000000', '000000']
['000000', '000000', '000000', '111111', '000000', '000000']
['000000', '000000', '000000', '000000', '111111', '000000']
['000000', '000000', '000000', '000000', '000000', '111111']

['100000', '010000', '001000', '000100', '000010', '000001']
['100000', '010000', '001000', '000100', '000010', '000001']
['100000', '010000', '001000', '000100', '000010', '000001']
['100000', '010000', '001000', '000100', '000010', '000001']
['100000', '010000', '001000', '000100', '000010', '000001']
['100000', '010000', '001000', '000100', '000010', '000001']
>>> 
>>> row0 = np.outer(0==np.arange(6), np.ones(6, dtype=int))
>>> rows =[np.roll(row0, i, axis=0) for i in range(6)]
>>> col0 = np.outer(np.ones(6, dtype=int), 0==np.arange(6))
>>> cols =[np.roll(col0, i, axis=1) for i in range(6)]
>>> 
>>> for block in (rows, cols):
...     for m in zip(*block):
...         print(list(map(''.join, map(map, 6*(str,), m))))
...     print()
... 
['111111', '000000', '000000', '000000', '000000', '000000']
['000000', '111111', '000000', '000000', '000000', '000000']
['000000', '000000', '111111', '000000', '000000', '000000']
['000000', '000000', '000000', '111111', '000000', '000000']
['000000', '000000', '000000', '000000', '111111', '000000']
['000000', '000000', '000000', '000000', '000000', '111111']

['100000', '010000', '001000', '000100', '000010', '000001']
['100000', '010000', '001000', '000100', '000010', '000001']
['100000', '010000', '001000', '000100', '000010', '000001']
['100000', '010000', '001000', '000100', '000010', '000001']
['100000', '010000', '001000', '000100', '000010', '000001']
['100000', '010000', '001000', '000100', '000010', '000001']
>>>
>>> rows =[np.add.outer(i==np.arange(6), np.zeros(6, dtype=int)) for i in range(6)]
>>> cols =[np.add.outer(np.zeros(6, dtype=int), i==np.arange(6)) for i in range(6)]
>>> 
>>> for block in (rows, cols):
...     for m in zip(*block):
...         print(list(map(''.join, map(map, 6*(str,), m))))
...     print()
... 
['111111', '000000', '000000', '000000', '000000', '000000']
['000000', '111111', '000000', '000000', '000000', '000000']
['000000', '000000', '111111', '000000', '000000', '000000']
['000000', '000000', '000000', '111111', '000000', '000000']
['000000', '000000', '000000', '000000', '111111', '000000']
['000000', '000000', '000000', '000000', '000000', '111111']

['100000', '010000', '001000', '000100', '000010', '000001']
['100000', '010000', '001000', '000100', '000010', '000001']
['100000', '010000', '001000', '000100', '000010', '000001']
['100000', '010000', '001000', '000100', '000010', '000001']
['100000', '010000', '001000', '000100', '000010', '000001']
['100000', '010000', '001000', '000100', '000010', '000001']

>>> rows = np.empty((6, 6, 6), dtype=int)
>>> rows[...] = np.identity(6)[..., None]
>>> cols = np.empty((6, 6, 6), dtype=int)
>>> cols[...] = np.identity(6)[:, None]
>>> 
>>> for block in (rows, cols):
...     for m in zip(*block):
...         print(list(map(''.join, map(map, 6*(str,), m))))
...     print()
... 
['111111', '000000', '000000', '000000', '000000', '000000']
['000000', '111111', '000000', '000000', '000000', '000000']
['000000', '000000', '111111', '000000', '000000', '000000']
['000000', '000000', '000000', '111111', '000000', '000000']
['000000', '000000', '000000', '000000', '111111', '000000']
['000000', '000000', '000000', '000000', '000000', '111111']

['100000', '010000', '001000', '000100', '000010', '000001']
['100000', '010000', '001000', '000100', '000010', '000001']
['100000', '010000', '001000', '000100', '000010', '000001']
['100000', '010000', '001000', '000100', '000010', '000001']
['100000', '010000', '001000', '000100', '000010', '000001']
['100000', '010000', '001000', '000100', '000010', '000001']
```